# Changing values to be selected in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do you change the value in a field from 'F' to 'FEMALE' using SQL in Microsoft Access. I used the following code but it does not work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN GENDER = 'F' THEN 'FEMALE' ELSE 'MALE' END AS Gender
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access does not support `CASE`, Use `IIF()`

```
SELECT IIF(GENDER = "F", "FEMALE", "MALE")
```

Answer (score 1):

MS ACCESS doesn't have a `case` expression. It does, however, have an `iif` expression (as suggested by Alex K.), or if you want something the more closely resembles a `case`, you could use a `switch` expression:

```
select
  switch(
    gender = "F", "Female",
    true, "Male"
  )
from some_table
```